# YUI add a class to datatable

Tags: yui

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to add a custom class to a YUI datatable.

e.g.,

```
<table class="custom-class">...</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In YUI3 it's just a matter of doing:

```
var datatable = new Y.DataTable(...);
datatable.get('boundingBox').addClass('custom-class');
```